# REST HAL Best Practice: Should I use links or nested JSON object when POSTing?

Tags: rest, post, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I would like to create a new `Employee` that reports to a `Manager`. An `Employee` cannot be POSTed without a `Manager`. Provided that I already have the `Manager` object and the URI for the `Manager`, is it a better practice to POST a `Manager` object nested:

```
{
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "manager": {"id":123, "firstname": "Albert", "lastname": "Doe"}
}
```

or using a link to manager:

```
{
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "_links" : {
      "manager" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/manager/123"
      }
    }
}
```

Does HAL require a link to the manager?

Note: I'm using Spring Data Rest (which uses HAL) and Spring HATEOAS. I found that `@RestResource(exported = false)` is required if POSTing with a nested object.

Comment: I think you can even use both if you want to.

Comment: @inf3rno - Yeah, I think per HAL spec either using `_links` or putting  the `manager` object within `_embedded` would be correct. Unfortunately though, Spring Data Rest doesn't seem to correctly deserialize `manager` if using `_links`.

Answer (score 0):

How about just posting manager's id? Your JSON would look like:

```
{
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "managerId": 123
}
```

And in your logic before creating your Employee you can check if the manager exists and fetch it.